# write parquet in python27 and read it with python 37

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, pyarrow

I'm writing a pandas dataframe to pyarrow.parquet with python2.7, and read it with python3.7.
I'm getting str columns as bytes.
If I write the parquet in python3.7 or read it with python2.7 I get those columns as standard string.

Can you please help me understanding it, and find a way to prevent it?

writing:

```
pa_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pa.parquet.write_table(pa_table, path)
```

reading:

`pq.read_table(path).to_pandas()`
Thanks!

Comment: what does `pq.read_table(path).schema` returns in both version of python?

Comment: when pq is written in python2: binary, when pq is written in python3 - string.

Comment: This has to do with changes to the str behaviour between python 2 and 3. You may want to read this: https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/strings.html